# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

> Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?
> У автора тот же код работает. У меня выдает ошибку.

```
let client = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

(async () => {
    let connection = await client.connect(connectionString, {useNewUrlParser: true});
    let db = connection.db('usersdb');
    let collection = db.collection('users');

    try{
        
        const result = await collection.aggregate([
            {$project:{'_id':0}},
            {$group:{'_id':'totalMonth':{$sum:{$multiply:['$age',12]}}}}
        ]).toArray();

        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        
    }finally {
        connection.close();
    }
})().catch(error => console.log(error));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пропущено `:$country,`

Comment: Да после id: не хватает country

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'_id':'$country',`

синтаксис создания объекта:
`{` тут пары `ключ:значение` через `,` `}`